# Unable to pull or push code on Looker UI using git actions

Tags: looker

I am developing the views and models in my personal branch. After that I am trying to pull the code from production and merge it. But I am not able to merge it, it says : Someone else has made changes to this branch. 35 commits to be pulled
or pull merge failed.

I tried to view project on bitbucket and then push the code to personal branch and merge to master. I have also tried creating a new branch. I am able to create new branch from git commands but not via Looker UI git actions. On Looker, it's showing access issues.
I expect that I should be able to follow all the steps on UI like merge and pull or push to production etc and views and models created after that should be visible to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with Looker support and they asked to try resetting the git connection and it worked for me.
Steps to follow for resetting git connection : https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/best-practices/how-to-migrate-to-a-new-git-repo#simple_solution

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this vague error, which was ultimately caused by my Master/Main branch being out of sync with the remote.

To resolve, I switched to the Master/Main branch while in Development Mode, which was behind, pulling from production, then switching back to my personal branch, which allowed me to Pull from Production without issue.